# Getting Certain Text From URL

Tags: c#, regex

I've been trying to do a couple things to this URL: "https://www.fiverr.com/categories/writing-translation/SEO-keyword-optimization-services"

First I need to parse out: writing-translation (Subject to change depending on the category). Then taking the '-' out of it so you would end up with: writing translation.

I've been trying myself with Regex, I am God AWFUL with it though, believe me I have trying though. If someone could give me an answer, and explain the Regex to me that they use, it would be awesome. Thank you so much.

i.e - my awful attempt (Just for the sake of it)

```
   string MainCategory_link = firefoxDriver.FindElementByXPath("//a[@class='gig- sub-cat js-gtm-event-auto']").GetAttribute("href");
   var Reg = new Regex("\".*?\"");
   var matches = Reg.Matches(MainCategory_link);
   foreach (var item in matches)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
   }
```

---

Updated code with segments attempt

```
string MainCategory_link = firefoxDriver.FindElementByXPath("//a[@class='gig-sub-cat js-gtm-event-auto']").GetAttribute("href");
var uri = new Uri(MainCategory_link);
foreach (var segment in uri.Segments)
{
    MessageBox.Show(segment[1].ToString());
 }
```

Comment: a google search could have saved you hours of headache as well

Comment: I rolled your edit back, because you wiped out the original code. Make sure you leave the original code intact, just post your edit below it (usually I use an underscore `_____` to separate them)

Comment: Your updated segments code is wrong. Each segment represents a unique segment from the URI, so doing `segment[1]` accesses the 2nd character in each segment string. Instead, just do `MessageBox.Show(segment);` No need for `.ToString()` either, because each segment is already a string. Make sure you read the MSDN documentation I linked to in my answer.

Comment: Yes I need to get the 'writing-translation' part though.

Comment: The point of looping over the segments is to show you what `uri.Segments` contains. You'll see that `writing-translation` is at the 2nd position, so then you'd access it via `uri.Segments[1]` without the need for a loop. Make sure you understand how a `foreach` loop works, as it iterates over each item inside an object that implements `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Uri class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows you to access different parts of the Uri via segments.

```
var uri = new Uri("https://www.fiverr.com/categories/writing-translation/SEO-keyword-optimization-services");
foreach(var segment in uri.Segments)
{
    MessageBox.Show(segment);
}

/* Output
categories
writing-translation
SEO-keyword-optimization-services
*/
```

Therefore, to retrieve `writing-translation` you'd do:

```
var uri = new Uri("https://www.fiverr.com/categories/writing-translation/SEO-keyword-optimization-services");
MessageBox.Show(uri[1]);
```

And of course, you should perform bounds checks anytime you're accessing something via index to make sure it exists and not get an `OutOfBoundsException`.

Never ever use Regex unless you are absolutely positive a better option doesn't already exist. Regex should always be a last resort. In fact, it's probably better if you don't know Regex at all, because you'll just keep trying to use it at all the wrong times.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much! It won't let me accept the answer yet, I will though when it lets me!

Comment: One thing though. I try to do: segment[1].ToString() and it throws an out of bounds exception? How?

Comment: @Frank Verify you're passing in the uri properly. You can edit your updated code into your question if you want. Also, always a good idea to do a bounds check before accessing an array or list via index.